# How to change mysql username and password

Tags: mysql, passwords

I have installed MySQL on my mac v10.8.5, with the default `username=''` and `password=''`.

How do I change these to `username='root'` and `password='root'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow thid step:

**Stop MySQL**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

**Start it in safe mode:**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished so open another shell/terminal window, log in without a password:

```
mysql -u root

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

Change the lowercase password to what you want – with single quotes.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

 \q
```

**Start MySQL**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

[Reference](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/)

Comment: you are right, but start mysql in safe mode sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rename user. In your case you need to add new user using such statements -

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD ('root');
```